# Google Chart Gannt avoid tooltip

Tags: charts, google-visualization, tooltip

From a research, I got that the tooltip that appears on Gannt Google Chart is not customizable, so I decided to override it capturing the hover event triggered by my gannt's rectangles as follow:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'onmouseover', function (e) {
        openTooltip(data, e.row);
    });
```

But now the problem is that the default tooltip popup still opens, how can I disable the default tooltip? (chart options/ custom jquery)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there aren't any options to remove the default tooltip on a Gantt chart

the tooltip is drawn using svg elements, which are added dynamically when you hover a bar
we can use a `MutationObserver` to know when the tooltip has been added
we can't remove the tooltip because it will break the chart
but we can make it invisible / all the elements transparent

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages:['gantt']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Task ID');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Task Name');
  data.addColumn('date', 'Start Date');
  data.addColumn('date', 'End Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Duration');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Percent Complete');
  data.addColumn('string', 'Dependencies');

  data.addRows([
    ['Research', 'Find sources',
     new Date(2015, 0, 1), new Date(2015, 0, 5), null,  100,  null],
    ['Write', 'Write paper',
     null, new Date(2015, 0, 9), daysToMilliseconds(3), 25, 'Research,Outline'],
    ['Cite', 'Create bibliography',
     null, new Date(2015, 0, 7), daysToMilliseconds(1), 20, 'Research'],
    ['Complete', 'Hand in paper',
     null, new Date(2015, 0, 10), daysToMilliseconds(1), 0, 'Cite,Write'],
    ['Outline', 'Outline paper',
     null, new Date(2015, 0, 6), daysToMilliseconds(1), 100, 'Research']
  ]);

  var options = {
    height: 275
  };

  var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
  var chart = new google.visualization.Gantt(container);

  google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    var observer = new MutationObserver(function (nodes) {
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(nodes, function(node) {
        if (node.addedNodes.length > 0) {
          Array.prototype.forEach.call(node.addedNodes, function(addedNode) {
            if ((addedNode.tagName === 'rect') && (addedNode.getAttribute('fill') === 'white')) {
              addedNode.setAttribute('fill', 'transparent');
              addedNode.setAttribute('stroke', 'transparent');
              Array.prototype.forEach.call(addedNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('text'), function(label) {
                label.setAttribute('fill', 'transparent');
              });
            }
          });
        }
      });
    });
    observer.observe(container, {
      childList: true,
      subtree: true
    });
  });

  chart.draw(data, options);

  function daysToMilliseconds(days) {
    return days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: Yes @WhiteHat, it has been very useful, I'm using your code to directly change the text inside of the tooltip box, using label.textContent.

Comment: Can I also know the number of textbox that will be iterated inside  Array.prototype.forEach.call(addedNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('text'), function (label) ?

Comment: sure --> `addedNode.parentNode.getElementsByTagName('text').length`

Comment: would this work in a react application context?  I tried it and I can't seem to get the `observer` to trigger

Comment: it should work, but hard to help without seeing the code. where are you referencing the observer? the observer code could actually be placed anywhere, such as in the document ready event.